# Problem Using PriorityQueue with Objects - Python

Tags: python, search, uniform

I'm trying to create a Uniform Cost Search algorithm. but I'm having a problem in storing nodes in the priorityqueue.

It works well till node D as shown in the output provided, and I'm not sure why. Any help will be appreciated.

The error says it can't compare nodes but I'm adding them as tuples so it can use the distacne for comparison

```
 class GraphEdge(object):
    def __init__(self, destinationNode, distance):
        self.node = destinationNode
        self.distance = distance

class GraphNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        self.edges = []

    def add_child(self, node, distance):
        self.edges.append(GraphEdge(node, distance))

    def remove_child(self, del_node):
        if del_node in self.edges:
            self.edges.remove(del_node)    

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, node_list):
        self.nodes = node_list
   
    def add_edge(self, node1, node2, distance):
        if node1 in self.nodes and node2 in self.nodes:
            node1.add_child(node2, distance)
            node2.add_child(node1, distance)

    def remove_edge(self, node1, node2):
        if node1 in self.nodes and node2 in self.nodes:
            node1.remove_child(node2)
            node2.remove_child(node1)

from queue import PriorityQueue

def build_path(root_node, goal_node):
    path = [goal_node]    
    add_parent(root_node, goal_node, path)
    return path

def add_parent(root_node, node, path):
    parent = node.parent
    path.append(parent)
    if parent == root_node:        
        return      
    else:
        add_parent(root_node, parent, path)
    

def ucs_search(root_node, goal_node):
    visited = set()                         
    queue = PriorityQueue()
    queue.put((0, root_node))
    visited_order = []
    
    while not queue.empty():
        current_node_priority, current_node  = queue.get()
        
        visited.add(current_node)
        visited_order.append(current_node.value)
        print("current_node:", current_node.value)

        if current_node == goal_node:
            print(visited_order)
            return current_node, build_path(root_node, goal_node)        
       
        for edge in current_node.edges:
            child = edge.node
            
            if child not in visited:          
                child.parent = current_node
                print("child:", child.value)
                queue.put(((current_node_priority + edge.distance), child))

node_u = GraphNode('U')
node_d = GraphNode('D')
node_a = GraphNode('A')
node_c = GraphNode('C')
node_i = GraphNode('I')
node_t = GraphNode('T')
node_y = GraphNode('Y')

graph = Graph([node_u, node_d, node_a, node_c, node_i, node_t, node_y])

graph.add_edge(node_u, node_a, 4)
graph.add_edge(node_u, node_c, 6)
graph.add_edge(node_u, node_d, 3)
graph.add_edge(node_d, node_c, 4)
graph.add_edge(node_a, node_i, 7)
graph.add_edge(node_c, node_i, 4)
graph.add_edge(node_c, node_t, 5)
graph.add_edge(node_i, node_y, 4)
graph.add_edge(node_t, node_y, 5)

goal, sequence  = ucs_search(node_a, node_y)
```

Output:

```
current_node: A
child: U
child: I
current_node: U
child: C
child: D
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-2d575db64232> in <module>
     19 graph.add_edge(node_t, node_y, 5)
     20 
---> 21 goal, sequence  = ucs_search(node_a, node_y)

<ipython-input-51-b26ec19983b6> in ucs_search(root_node, goal_node)
     36                 child.parent = current_node
     37                 print("child:", child.value)
---> 38                 queue.put(((current_node_priority + edge.distance), child))
     39 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\queue.py in put(self, item, block, timeout)
    147                             raise Full
    148                         self.not_full.wait(remaining)
--> 149             self._put(item)
    150             self.unfinished_tasks += 1
    151             self.not_empty.notify()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\queue.py in _put(self, item)
    231 
    232     def _put(self, item):
--> 233         heappush(self.queue, item)
    234 
    235     def _get(self):

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'GraphNode' and 'GraphNode'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two tuples in the queue have the same distance, the priority queue needs to tiebreak based on the priority value of the corresponding `GraphNode`s. Since the `__lt__` function isn't defined for `GraphNode`s, this will cause an error. (The `__lt__` function defines how two `GraphNode`s can be compared using the `<` operator.)

To resolve, define the `__lt__` function for the `GraphNode` class. This is the function that Python calls when comparing two `GraphNodes`:

```py
class GraphNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        self.edges = []

    def add_child(self, node, distance):
        self.edges.append(GraphEdge(node, distance))

    def remove_child(self, del_node):
        if del_node in self.edges:
            self.edges.remove(del_node)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value
```

Comment: Thanks BrokenBenchmark, that solved my problem.